# Team Foundation Server 2010 + Working Offline Then Online

Tags: tfs

I have got a VS2010 solution managed by an instance of TFS2010.
My solution is on the hard drive of computer C-1.

I have copied all the solution to the hard drive of computer C-2 not connected to the TFS instance.
Then I have made some changes to the solution via VS2010 : Creating new files, modifying existing files, ....

I need to pursue my work on the solution on C-1.
Is there a way to replace the solution on C-1 with the solution on C-2 ?
And then I want TFS to check my solution and update server files.

Thanks in advance for your future help

Comment: Have you tried manual overwriting your solution on c-1 with c2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, copy the latest sources to computer C1 (taking care to back up anything important from it that you don't want to overwrite first)

You can then use the offline mode of vs to find your changes. Unplug your net connection and run vs and it'll go offline. Plug the net connection back in, and choose File > Source Control > Go online. It will discover your changes ready to check in.

Or do it manually. In source control, right click on the root folder and check out the entire thing. Then select all from your pending changes and undo checkout. When it asks if you wish to discard your changes, *carefully* choose No All. You will be left with only your changed files checked out.

Note that these techniques will both fail to varying degrees for deleted, renamed and created files, so you may still have a bit of manual tidying up to do if you're done more than just editing existing files.

Comment: in VS2012, there is no "File > Source Control > Go Online". But you can right click on the Solution Explorer and Go Online.